# How to ignore IE "Text Size" option to display exact web page?

Tags: css

Please have a look at this beautiful website :  http://www.snipe.net/

If you are using MS IE, choose a different "Text Size" from your browser "View" tab.

You can see nothing on the page changes. This is not often seen on most of websites, even Google.

I wonder how this could be achieved? Tried to search for a solution but was not lucky.

I got this question because the website I am going to build has different lookings
according to the "Text Size" option. It would be great if everything is the same regardless the Text Size user chooses.

If anyone can give me some ideas that would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify your text size in "px", for example:

```
.specificSize
{
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Be sure to check any accessibility requirements before you do this. This can cause problems if people are extremely farsided and can't read too well.

Comment: Oh! didn't know that, thanks!
BTW, what if some images are 'bad' when choosing different 'Text Size'?

Comment: *farsighted. Though people being transformed by Gary Larson's a cool idea.

Answer (score 1):

The font sizes are all in pixels.

Answer (score -1):

## ***This behaviour is BAD!***

Some people might not have eyesight as good as yours. Allow them to increase it if *they want* it.

Comment: Well, they can Ctrl++ nevertheless. Disabling the "Text Size" feature would not dramatically bring down usability, I assume.

Comment: You can still _zoom_ using any decent browser - even IE8's zoom seems to work these days. I would recommend testing your layout in at least "larger" and "smaller" as well as "normal" text sizes though.